# I'm getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when I connect to JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I'm running a server using Tomcat 7.0 in Eclipse.
I have a html file to link to a Servlet file, which has a form to input the value.
When I input any value in the html file, it forwards to the servlet file, and the servlet file has some codes to connect JDBC.
The code is quite simple.

```
data = request.getPrameter("name");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

I've imported everything to be used.
Also, in the tomcat server, I added permission in catalina.policy

```
grant{
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1-65535", "connect,resolve";
};
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.
I'm happy to give you more information if needed!
Please help me :)

Comment: I've just found out that there was a "detailMessage".
It goes: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")

Comment: Without seeing your full code, have you given the following website a look, http://craftingjava.blogspot.com/2012/06/javalangexceptionininitializererror.html?

Comment: @Web2pyuser : Add pertinent information like that detailmessage to your actual question. Don't use comments for that, but edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had detailMessage saying access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read").
So I added permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.encoding", "read"; and all fixed
It'd be great if this helps anyone who's in trouble

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem when I used jdbc connect to teradata database,
that because it need two jar files but I just gave one jar file:
jdbc_driver_loc = '/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop/jars/terajdbc4-16.20.00.06.jar'

```
jpype._jexception.ExceptionInInitializerErrorPyRaisable: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

when I added the other one, it works:

jdbc_driver_loc = '/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop/jars/terajdbc4-16.20.00.06.jar,/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop/jars/tdgssconfig-16.20.00.06.jar'

Whole sample like that:

```
[root@myhost transfer]# cat test_conn.py 
import jaydebeapi
from contextlib import closing


jclassname='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
jdbc_driver_loc = '/opt/spark-2.3.1/jars/terajdbc4-16.20.00.06.jar,/opt/spark-2.3.1/jars/tdgssconfig-16.20.00.06.jar'
jdbc_driver_name = 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
host='my_teradata.address'

url='jdbc:teradata://' + host + '/TMODE=TERA'
login="teradata_user_name"
psw="teradata_passwd"

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  A_TERADATA_TABLE_NAME where month_key='202009'"


conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=jdbc_driver_name,
                                  url=url, 
                                  driver_args=[login, psw],
                                  jars=jdbc_driver_loc.split(","))

with closing(conn) as conn:
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)
        print(cur.fetchall())
   
[root@myhost transfer]# python test_conn.py
[(7734133,)]
[root@myhost transfer]#
```